# Apache Storm Supervisor showing : kill: sending signal to 5517 failed: No such process

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-storm, nimbus

When i start my supervisor using `bin/storm supervisor` supervisor shows the following error:

> kill: sending signal to 5517 failed: No such process.

**storm.yml**

```
storm.zookeeper.servers: ["localhost"]
nimbus.seeds: ["localhost"]
storm.local.dir: "/home/usename/Documents/Storm/datadir/storm"
storm.zookeeper.port: 2181
supervisor.slots.ports:
- 6700
- 6701
- 6702
- 6703
ui.port: 8087
initLimit: 30
syncLimit: 10
storm.messaging.transport : "org.apache.storm.messaging.netty.Context"
```

**zoo.cfg**

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/home/username/Documents/Storm/datadir/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
```

my folder structure is :

```
/home/username/Documents/Storm/apache-storm-1.2.3/
/home/username/Documents/Storm/datadir/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.14/
```

steps to start Storm and zookeeper :

```
- cd /home/username/Documents/Storm/datadir/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.14
- bin/zkServer.sh start
- cd /home/username/Documents/Storm/apache-storm-1.2.3
- bin/storm nimbus
- bin/storm supervisor
- bin/storm ui
```

after i execute these commands my supervisor shows error:

> kill: sending signal to 5517 failed: No such process

Comment: Does the supervisor keep running, or does it terminate? Does this prevent you from running topologies?

Comment: Supervisor continuously shows kill: sending signal to 5517 failed: No such process.